# PrimeFaces p:printer doesn't print p:inputTextarea content

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a question about [`<p:printer>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/printer.xhtml). Here is my code snippet:

```
<h:panelGroup id="layout1">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.value1}: " />
    <p:inputTextarea value="#{bean.value2}" ></p:inputTextarea>
</h:panelGroup>

<p:commandButton value="Print" type="button">
    <p:printer target="layout1" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Problem is, when I click Print, after opening the print page, my `<p:inputTextarea>` is blank, and not displayed text that I previously entered, while the `<h:outputText>` is correctly displayed.

My question is: Is it possible to show on print page the entered text form `<p:inputTextarea>`?

Comment: Tiny, thank you for advice. I apsolutely agree with you, that PDF viewer will show the old value of `<p:inputTextarea>`, i.e. bean property, and i can't find way to update it with entered value.

Comment: Why don't you require the user to submit the form before printing it? It's otherwise indeed a strange functional requirement.

Comment: BalusC, user has a two options: Save (i.e. submit the form), and Print. After saving (submiting form), if user click Print, everything is fine, but if user click Print before (without) saving, the entered text won't be displayed. I tried with ajax-submiting enetered value on blur of the `<p:inputTextarea>`, and after that the bean property is filled indeed, but Printer doesn't "see" that. Only thing i can do is to disable printing before saving, as you suggested. Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that I have not found the right answer to the concrete question, and after consultation with some of people I have come to the conclusion that I will solve the problem if I disable printing of the page before submitting it. So, when the page is printed after previously submit, the entered values are properly updated and ready for printing (which was not the case when attempting to print before submitting).

So, people thank you for your suggestions!